# How do I correctly concatenate this php string

Tags: php, string, curl, concatenation

```
$name = $_POST["fname"];
echo $name;
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n
  \"DisplayName\": \" ".$name." \",\n    
  \"PrimaryEmailAddr\": {\n \"Address\": \"jdrew@myemail.com\"\n    }\n}\n",
```

I am trying to make a POST request with the details in the form which actioned the php file, 
the echo prints the correct information, ive tried + and . and { and "" and all manner of things to no avail, hopefully anyone with an ounce of know how can fix this one , this is m first time near php :/

edit:

```
$jsons = array(

  "DisplayName"=> "scsKing's Groceries", 
  "Suffix"=> "Jr", 
  "Title"=> "Mr", 
  "MiddleName"=> "B", 
  "Notes"=> "Here are other details.", 
  "FamilyName"=> "King", 

  "GivenName"=> "James"
);

$JsonString = json_encode($jsons);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123146505733159/customer?minorversion=41",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $JsonString,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
```

Would this be the correct format, it returns cURL Error #:Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

thanks

Comment: please post the result of var_dump($name)

Comment: Don't create your own json. Create an array, then use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: var_dump($name)
result : string(3)

I shall give it a try

Comment: I have tried to create the json string I have updated the main post , could you advise if thats correct